# Generate unique identifier in powerapps

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I want that whenever a new item is added to my "`Vacation Requests`" list from powerapps, a new identifier should be generated in a text column called "RNO" and it should have format like : UserName_CreatedDate_CreatedTime. I created the calculated column called "Request Number" and in powerapps i added the following formula :
`Text(Concatenate(User().FullName,"_",Text(Created,"[$-en-US]mmddyy"),"_",Text(Created,"[$-en-US] hhmm") ) )`.

I want that this value generated should be copied to the `"RNO"` field.The Request number is properly generated but the RNO field is not updated properly in SharePoint.

> PowerApps Request Number: Kirtikulkarni_062917_1025   -- calculated
>   PowerApps RNO: Kirtikulkarni_062917_1025     --Text SharePoint List
>   RNO : KirtiKulkarni_

As you can see the datetimestamp is not updated. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution!